# Cannot Connect Slicer to Multiple Pivot Tables - Error #424 "Object Required"

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, slicers

I am trying to connect a Slicer to multiple Pivot Tables using the method described here: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/05/slicers-and-slicercaches/

First, I loop through my Pivot Tables and create a slicer for each:

```
wkbDash.SlicerCaches.Add(wksPivots.PivotTables(sPTName), sSlicerName). _
    Slicers.Add wksSlicers, , sSlicerName, sSlicerName, 1, 1, 50, 100
```

Then I loop through my Slicers and try to hook them to each Pivot Table

Problem: I am getting an Error #424 "Object Required" on this line:

```
wkbDash.SlicerCaches(objSlicer).PivotTables.AddPivotTable 
(wksPivots.PivotTables(varPTNames(i, 1)))
```

Code to hook Slicers to Pivot Tables:

```
' Declarations
Dim objSlicerCache  As SlicerCache
Dim objSlicer       As Slicer
Dim objPT           As PivotTable
Dim varPTNames      As Variant
Dim wksDefPivots    As Worksheet
Dim wkbDash         As Workbook
Dim i               As Integer

' Initialize Variables
Set wkbDash = Workbooks(sDash)
Set wksDefPivots = Workbooks(sDash).Worksheets(sDefPivots)
varPTNames = wksDefPivots.Range("A2:A" & FindLastRow(wksDefPivots)).Value2
i = 0

' Procedure
    For Each objSlicerCache In Workbooks(sDash).SlicerCaches
        For Each objSlicer In objSlicerCache.Slicers
            For i = LBound(varPTNames) To UBound(varPTNames)
               wkbDash.SlicerCaches(objSlicer).PivotTables.AddPivotTable (wksPivots.PivotTables(varPTNames(i, 1)))
            Next i
        Next objSlicer
    Next objSlicerCache
```

Based on Bob's comments I have modified the loop to try and hook the Pivot Tables to the SlicerCache object instead of the Slicer. I am still getting the Error #424 "Object Required"

Revised Loop:

```
    For Each objSlicerCache In Workbooks(sDash).SlicerCaches
        For j = LBound(varPTNames) To UBound(varPTNames)
           objSlicerCache.PivotTables.AddPivotTable (wksPivots.PivotTables(varPTNames(j, 1)))
        Next j
    Next objSlicerCache
```

**Major Update:**
I Have revised the code and am very close. New code sequence:
   1. Create 1 PivotCache
   2. Use PivotCache to create many PivotTables
   3. Create 1 SlicerCache from first PivotTable
   4. Add additional PivotTables to SlicerCache
   5. Loop through each PivotTable in SlicerCache and create a slicer.

Good news: All this code works. It creates many slicers, and each slicer will filter all the Pivot Tables

**The Problem:** All the Slicers are only filtering One Field (See Image) rather than each slicer providingng a different field to filter.

Code:

```
   For Each objSlicerCache In wkbDash.SlicerCaches
        objSlicerCache.Delete
    Next objSlicerCache

    sRF = Worksheets(sDefPivots).Range("B2").Value
    sPT = Worksheets(sDefPivots).Range("A2").Value

    Set objPT = Worksheets(sPivots).PivotTables(sPT)
    Set objPF = Worksheets(sPivots).PivotTables(sPT).PivotFields(sRF)

    Set objSlicerCache = wkbDash.SlicerCaches.Add(objPT, objPF.Name)

    Set objPT = Nothing
    Set objPF = Nothing

    For Each objPT In Worksheets(sPivots).PivotTables
        objSlicerCache.PivotTables.AddPivotTable objPT
    Next objPT

    For Each objSlicerCache In wkbDash.SlicerCaches
        For Each objPT In objSlicerCache.PivotTables
            objSlicerCache.Slicers.Add wksSlicers, , objPT.Name, objPT.Name, 1, 1, 50, 100
        Next objPT
    Next objSlicerCache
```

[Screenshot of Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enI4R.png)

Comment: I went back to the code that creates the Pivot Tables and noticed that it creates a PivotTableCache for each Pivot Table, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: It could. I'd suggest that you have a look at all of the different objects in your immediate window (i.e. debug window), and see which one isn't coming up as an object and so is throwing the error. For more on how to do that, see [this](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/). By the way, part of what I don't understand is that it appears that you're already adding the pivot tables by "creating a slicer for each" before you get into all this, just the other way around. What are you doing different here?

Comment: You are correct, I am now re-thining this. Before I would get a list of PTs then create a PivotCache & PT for each one. Then create a slicer for each PT. Then try and link each Slicer to every other PT. But now I am going to try and create One PivotCache and use it to create each PT. Then create One SlicerCache and use it for each Slicer. If all the PTs have the same PTCache and i use a PT to create a SlicerCache, and create every Slicer using that SC then I *HOPE* they will all connect. This is my first time programming with PT, Caches, and Slicers so i have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: The doc's a bit flimsy on what matches up with what, too. I'd say debug will be your friend there, so you can evaluate individual values in individual items and compare them.

Comment: I agree. Right now I am just throwing everything on the wall to see what sticks. I'll update once more to show where I am now.

Comment: @BobRodes BTW I appreciate your help on this today

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicercaches) it's evident that you have a syntax problem. To get an individual `Slicer` object:

```
wkbDash.SlicerCaches("someString")
```

This is consistent with general `Collection` syntax:

```
myCollection("aKeyValue")
```

Or:

```
myCollection(anOffsetInteger)
```

You are putting an object reference as the key value, rather than a string or integer.

Now, `PivotTables` is a collection associated with a single `SlicerCache` object. Your outer `For Each` is iterating through these, so if you're going to add a pivot table in each iteration, you need to do it to your iterated object, so:

```
For Each objSlicerCache In Workbooks(sDash).SlicerCaches
    For i = LBound(varPTNames) To UBound(varPTNames)
           objSlicerCache.PivotTables.AddPivotTable (wksPivots.PivotTables(varPTNames(i, 1)))
    Next i
Next objSlicerCache
```

You can't iterate the `Slicers` collection in each `SlicerCache` object inside the loop, and add the pivot table to the individual `Slicer` objects, because the object model isn't set up to associate a `Slicer` object directly with a `PivotTable` object. If you look in the doc, you'll see that the `SlicerCache` object has a `PivotTables` property, while the `Slicers` and `Slicer` objects do not.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then it should be: > SlicerCaches(objSlicer.name) ?

Comment: @Chris I was just going to edit to suggest that. I'm sorry, I've never worked with the `SlicerCaches` and `Slicers` collections myself and I can't test it, but that's what I'd try.

Comment: I replaced it with this: 
    wkbDash.SlicerCaches(objSlicer.name).PivotTables.AdPivotTable (wksPivots.PivotTables(varPTNames(i,1))) but am still getting the Error #424 Object Required Error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but am still getting the same error

Comment: @Chris I had to read up on the object model. What I have up there now shouldn't get the error, but I'm not sure it's what you want. If it doesn't do what you want, please explain.

Comment: I tried your alternative and received a Error #438 Object doesn't support this property or method on line: 
    objSlicerCache.Slicers(i).PivotTables.AddPivotTable (wksPivots.PivotTables(varPTNames(j, 1)))

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I did a little more reading and edited my answer, explaining why. `PivotTables` are associated wtih `SlicerCache`, not `Slicer`. So no, the `Slicer` object doesn't support the `PivotTables` property. Why do you want it to, exactly?

Comment: Because I'm ignorant. I just want the slicer to filter multiple Pivot Tables like when you hook them to multiple PTs via the connections. I will try and rewrite the loop to loop on the SlicerCaches.

Comment: I have updated my question with the proposed loop and error received

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**
Code steps:
1. Create Pivot Tables from one Pivot Cache
2. For each Pivot Table, create a Slicer Cache
3. For each Slicer Cache, create a Slicer
4. For each Slicer Cache, loop through Pivot Tables and add them to the SC

**Code:**

```
' Procedure

    For Each objSlicerCache In wkbDash.SlicerCaches
        objSlicerCache.Delete
    Next objSlicerCache

    varSlicers = wksDefPivots.Range("A2:B" & CStr(FindLastRow(wksDefPivots))).Value2
    For i = LBound(varSlicers, 1) To UBound(varSlicers, 1)
        Set objPT = Worksheets(sPivots).PivotTables(CStr(varSlicers(i, 1)))
        Set objPF = Worksheets(sPivots).PivotTables(CStr(varSlicers(i, 1))).PivotFields(CStr(varSlicers(i, 2)))
        Set objSlicerCache = wkbDash.SlicerCaches.Add(objPT, objPF.Name) 'Create SlicerCache for each Pivot Table
    Next i

    For Each objSlicerCache In wkbDash.SlicerCaches
        For Each objPT In objSlicerCache.PivotTables
            objSlicerCache.Slicers.Add wksSlicers, , objPT.Name, objPT.Name, 1, 1, 50, 100 'Add Slicers for each Pivot Table
        Next objPT
    Next objSlicerCache

    Set objSlicerCache = Nothing
    Set objPT = Nothing

    Call FormatSlicers(sSlicers) 'Format size & location of slicers

   For Each objSlicerCache In wkbDash.SlicerCaches
        For Each objPT In wksPivots.PivotTables
                objSlicerCache.PivotTables.AddPivotTable objPT 'Add every Pivot Table to every SlicerCache
        Next objPT
    Next objSlicerCache
```